# Can you force a full render of a list in Office Fabric?

Tags: office-ui-fabric, office-fabric

I'm working with a List in Office Fabric, specifically a DetailsList. Within my list, I have a number of images that are pretty expensive to render, as well as a pretty big list of rows. Unfortunately, this means when I scroll down, there's a huge lag as the page is re-rendering new images (also frustratingly because it destroys the previous images, if I scroll back up it's similarly laggy).

Is there a way to force a render of the entire list so that it doesn't have to re-render when you scroll up or down? I don't mind having a long initial loading time as long as the actual scrolling portion doesn't have a high latency/isn't slow or jerky.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable virtualization by returning false in the DetailsList's `onShouldVirtualize` callback.

The team is actively working on improving List / DetailsList virtualization in the coming months.

Relevant documentation pages describing the above prop:

- https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/detailslist
- https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/blob/738e270892f99957aecf567e4b107f8e4cf86176/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/components/DetailsList/DetailsList.types.ts#L253